# Force Windows Explorer to only treat ALL clicks as FULL clicks, not HALF clicks

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

On Windows 10 Windows Explorer often treats some clicks on the navigational panel as "half" clicks; the folder becomes highlighted however the file listing does not update.

How do I *force* Windows Explorer to treat *all clicks* as "full clicks"?

Comment: On my 3 Windows 10 machines here, if I firmly click on my mouse, the folder contents refresh. No issue at all. (1) with due respect, are you clicking firmly? (2) update the mouse driver  (3) open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run in order:  1. dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  2.  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  3.  SFC  /SCANNOW   . Check all the above, restart and test.

Comment: @John If the computer registers a click then it's a click. I imagine it's some kind of excess "feature" that someone thought would be "cool" that is only **explicitly annoying and pointless**. I'm not going to bother with generic "try-this", that belongs on answers.microsoft.com which I avoid like the plague.

Comment: There is something wrong somewhere. Zero issues on all my computers here. And, no, what you have above is for sure not a cool Windows 10 feature.

Comment: Which type of pointing device do you use? Is it a mouse or trackpad / similar?

Comment: What exactly is a half click?

Answer (score 0):

If the mouse is moved in the midst of *onmousedown*... *onmouseup* events, it might cause that issue by treating the move as *drag & drop*. Make sure the mouse doesn't move in midst of a click.

You can try changing [drag & drop settings](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-drag-drop-sensitivity-avoid-accidental-move-files/) to avoid that issue:

- Open Regedit.
- Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`.
- Increase `DragHeight` and `DragWidth` values from the default 4, e.g., to 8, each.